# Are there different tooltip mechanisms?

Tags: overlays, tooltip

I experience some weird behavior with tooltips:

```
(progn
  (let* ((start (point))
         (end (progn (insert "test") (point)))
         (ov (make-overlay start end)))
    (overlay-put ov 'help-echo
                 (propertize "xxx" 'display '(image :type jpeg :file "~/foo.jpg"))))
  (display-buffer-other-frame (get-buffer-create "dummy")))
```

Evaluating this code and moving the mouse pointer over `test` I get a tooltip
displaying the image file `foo.jpg`. The tooltip appears as a box with a
light yellow background color with sharp corners.

But the moment I click into any frame/window the tooltip changes. Now
the tooltip contains no image but the text `xxx`. Furthermore the
tooltip appears as a transparent black box with rounded corners.

What's going on here? Are their two different tooltip mechanisms with
different capabilities?

If I remove the code lines creating/displaying buffer `dummy` I 
never see the tooltip with the image (the first one); I see only the tooltip
with the text `xxx` (the second one).

**Edit:** Here are screenshots of the two different tooltips.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see that behavior of seeing `xxx` after clicking in a window or frame. I'm using Emacs 26.3 on MS Windows.

Comment: BTW, why do you show the code for displaying a buffer named `dummy`? What does that have to do with your question? The overlay is not even in that buffer, etc. If it's irrelevant then please consider removing it. If it's relevant then maybe explain how so, etc.

Comment: Yes, this dummy buffer/frame is relevant as described in the last paragraph. I need this dummy frame to see the image tooltip, otherwise I only see the "xxx" tooltip. I've tested it with Emacs 25.2.2 and 28.0.50.

Comment: Then I don't understand - maybe someone else does. Displaying a buffer after you've already created an overlay in some other buffer should have no effect on that overlay. But you don't show all of the relevant code, I expect. Perhaps you need to say something about the buffer you are in when you evaluate the code.

Comment: It's `emacs -Q foo.el` and `C-x C-e`, no more. I do not evaluate any other code than the one I posted.

Comment: Ask this on the emacs-help mailing list. That is read by the maintainers too.

Comment: I also can't replicate the issue either, and including the `display-buffer-other-frame` form in the code actively causes problems in my testing, by creating a new unwanted frame.  It all works fine for me without that form, such that I always see the picture appear when hovering over the "test" text.  GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw scroll bars).